# Какого рода ошибки можно обрабатывать с помощью Flask-WTF?

Tags: flask, flask-wtf

Приведите примеры ошибок простым языком.

1. Например, наверное, это может быть ошибка авторизации пользователя.
2. Или, ошибка с подсказкой, если пользователь осуществляет поиск, но введенного им слова в БД не существует?

**form.<переменная поля>.errors**

и здесь переменная поля какая может быть? Расскажите подробнее про эту переменную поля.

Comment: Какие поля в вашей форме есть, такая переменная и может быть.

Comment: и RadioField (чекбокс) тоже?

Comment: Тоже. . . . . .

Comment: получается, тема, которая в заголовке моего вопроса - это валидация

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Давайте по порядку** 
`form.<переменная поля>.errors` - ошибки валидации, который прописываются в FlaskForm с помощью параметра **validators** для строки. Вот пример:

```
email = StringField("E-mail", validators=[DataRequired(), Email('Incorrect email')])
```

**<переменная поля>** любая, которую вы прописали.

**Примеры ошибок:**
`DataRequired()` -> Отсутствие данных в поле 
`Email('Incorrect email')` -> Пользователь некорректно ввёл email в поле 
`EqualTo("password", message="Passwords must match")` -> Поле не совпадает с полем password (Прописанном в том же классе FlaskForm) 
**И т.д.**